# how to call a microservice rest endpoint which takes int for realtime responses of each user

Tags: java

This is more of an architectural question in programming to understand the possibility of my thinking. I have a java microservice rest endpoint that takes an int value. For example, If the int value is 10, the endpoint will get 10 users from database and run through the business logic one user at a time and update different things. This works but I want to know whats the best way to see response of each user at real time to know if there are any unknown exceptions and had to stop the job from running further. I am not sure if postman can do this or an executable? If so, please suggest how and I will get going. Thanks!

Comment: #1 Do you want a kind of dashboard with stats of your microservice? Stats like count of success delivered responses, error responses, timeouts, etc ? #2 Also, Do you want to see in this dashboard the request and response of any invokation? #3 Do you need to see the log of any invokation, maybe  with filters like: date, user, endpoint, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to see the processing as real-time stream of responses per each user in a task - you have to implement your microservice in reactive way.

If it is not possible - instead of executing one task of 10 users, you can feed you service by small chunks (10 x 1 user) in parallel threads from the client side.

To achieve it, you can create a simple executable leveraging one of the reactive frameworks. For example, [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/How-To-Use-RxJava) or, in if you are using Spring/Spring Boot, [WebFlux](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux/webflux.html) framework

Or, you can try to use some tools like [Apache Jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), if you prefer to configure something instead of developing.